# Trouble with nested tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, nesting

I am using nested table environments in the following snippet:

```
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX lX}

  COURSEWORK & Machine Learning, Probabilitistic Learning, Probabilistic Graphical Models, Intermediate Statistics A \& B, Statistical Methodology I \& II, Statistical Computing, Information Retreival, Principles of Data Management, Data Structures, Computer Architecture\\
 \\*
  COURSEWORK & \begin{tabular}{ l l l }
   Machine Learning & Probabilistic Learning & Probabilistic Graphical Models \\
   Intermediate Statistics & Statistical Computing & Statistical Methods \\
   Principles of Data  & Data Structures & Computer Architecture \\
  \end{tabular}\\

\end{tabularx}
```

which produces following document:

[image]

Now, there are three issues with this rendering:

1. The tabular listing of courses seems to have extra indentation (note the entries are already left justified) &
2. The section title 'COURSEWORK' for the tabular listing appears in front of middle row, I would like it to start from the top of the tabular listing. I tried using `\multirow` but it does not take the section title above the middle row.

Please suggest how these can be achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `\tabcolsep` length at the beginning and at the end of the `tabular`s using `@{}`; the alignment issue can be corrected using `t` for the optional argument of `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r X l X @{}}
  COURSEWORK & Machine Learning, Probabilitistic Learning, Probabilistic Graphical Models, Intermediate Statistics A \& B, Statistical Methodology I \& II, Statistical Computing, Information Retreival, Principles of Data Management, Data Structures, Computer Architecture\\
 \\*
  COURSEWORK & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l l l @{} }
   Machine Learning & Probabilistic Learning & Probabilistic Graphical Models \\
   Intermediate Statistics & Statistical Computing & Statistical Methods \\
   Principles of Data  & Data Structures & Computer Architecture \\
  \end{tabular}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]